# How to obtain individual elements from java arraylist to jsp script?

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, arraylist

/* java code */

```
String abc=request.getParameter("name");

dbLayer cmmntdb=new dbLayer();

ArrayList<String> cmmnts=cmmntdb.getcmmnts(abc);

int size=cmmnts.size();

for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{


String pk_cmmnt_id=cmmnts.get(0);

String name=cmmnts.get(1);

String comment=cmmnts.get(2);

String updated_at=cmmnts.get(3);
```

/* java script */

```
document.getElementById("cmnt_id").innerHTML="<%=pk_cmmnt_id.toString()%>";
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML="<%=name.toString()%>";
document.getElementById("upd_at").innerHTML="<%=updated_at.toString()%>";
document.getElementById("cmnt").innerHTML="<%=comment.toString()%>";
```

followed by html content including labels of above id's.

}

for loop is closed here.

---

### Output window while running project in tomcat server 6:

ID:1

Name:rahul

Update_at:2014-07-05 22:54:11.0

Comment:good

ID:

Name:

Update_at:

Comment:

ID:

Name:

Update_at:

Comment:

---

here the html contents are generated up to the size of array-list, labels in first html table is filled with array-list element **but all other tables generated by loop is empty (not filled by array-list values)** . How to get all array-list values in JSP? size of my array list is 29. i have to get all values from array-list in my output window. 
any piece of code is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: System.out abc and tel wat u get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 issues with your for-loop. First each iteration overwrites the same field. Second the list inside the loop is indexed by constant values. So no matter how many times the loop is executed it always access the same value. And third the loop is incrementing `i` by one and inside you are accessing 4 elements at a time this may cause invalid data. So assuming this is code is a jsp scriptlet you need to modify the loop like

```
<% for(int i = 0; i < comments.size(); i+=4) {             
%>
    <label>ID: <%= comments.get(i) %></label><br/>
    <label>Name: <%= comments.get(i+1) %></label><br/>
    <label>Update_at: <%= comments.get(i+2) %></label><br/>
    <label>Comment: <%= comments.get(i+3) %></label><br/>
<% } %>
```

You can modify the html inside. Also with this approach you should be sure that the array size is a multiple of 4 else you'll end up in ArrayOutOfBoundException.

Having said that I would say this isn't a good approach. For such requirements you should consider creating a value object and the then iterate it using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). I this case create a VO called Comment like

```
public class Comment {
    private String commentId;
    private String commentedBy;
    private Date updateDate;
    private String commentText;

    public String getCommentId() {
        return commentId;
    }
    public void setCommentId(String commentId) {
        this.commentId = commentId;
    }
    public String getCommentedBy() {
        return commentedBy;
    }
    public void setCommentedBy(String commentedBy) {
        this.commentedBy = commentedBy;
    }
    public Date getUpdateDate() {
        return updateDate;
    }
    public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate) {
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }
    public String getCommentText() {
        return commentText;
    }
    public void setCommentText(String commentText) {
        this.commentText = commentText;
    }
}
```

Then modify your databse cla to return list of comments object.

```
List<Comment> cmmnts = cmmntdb.getcmmnts(abc);
```

Set this list to request in your server side code (servlet) like `request.setAttribute("comments", cmmnts)` and then in jsp you can generate the html like

```
<c:forEach items="${comments}" var="comment">
    <label>ID: ${comment.commentId}</label><br/>
    <label>Name: ${comment.commentedBy}</label><br/>
    <label>Update_at: <fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${comment.updateDate}" /></label><br/>
    <label>Comment: ${comment.commentText}</label><br/> 
</c:forEach>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: where do i have to add request.setAttribute("comments", cmmnts)? in db layer, i am obtaining data from result set using while loop Comment.add(rsval.getString("pk_cmmnt_id"));
Comment.add(rsval.getString("name"));
Comment.add(rsval.getString("comment"));Comment.add(rsval.getString("updated_at"));

Comment: What is your server side framework? Is it pure servlets or struts or spring?? Based on that you need to set it appropriately. The while loop in your comment is essentially adding string to a list, which is same as the code you have in your question. If you are planning to modify your code based on the value object-jstl approach I mentioned the please let me know the technology you use and i can create a sample code for you.

Answer (score 0):

What your are doing is updating the sample HTML elements in all iteration, so please refer to this good example on how to Creating Dynamic Tables using JSP

http://www.developer.com/lang/other/article.php/724181/JSP-Creating-Dynamic-Tables.htm

Thanks